# Spring - HttpServletRequest object null when deleting JSESSIONID cookie?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, nullpointerexception, controller

I am testing a new functionality in my web app where i'm allowing the user to remain signed in even after the browing session expires.  In order to achieve this, i have a "Keep me logged in" checkbox on my login page.  Upon successful login, a cookie is created containing the userID and the login process continues normally.  The first thing the first method in my main controller does is check for the presence of that cookie, read the userId in it, set the User object in the session correctly and bypass the login process, going directly to the home page.  When the user signs out, the cookie is recreated with an expiration of 0 which means it's automatically deleted.

My Spring sessions last 30 minutes currently.  I have successfully tested everything but i'm trying to replicate the Spring session expiring, which gets rid of the User object in memory and would normally force the user to login.  In order to replicate it, i am deleting the JSESSIONID cookie from Chrome.  When i do that, the HttpServletRequest object (which I am checking cookies on) is null.

Here is the first code that runs in my main controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) 
{
    if (session.getAttribute("loggedInUser") != null)
    {
        return "home";
    }
    else
    {
        String userId = null;

        for (Cookie cookie : request.getCookies())
        {
            if (cookie.getName().compareTo("MDHISStaySignedIn") == 0)
            {
                userId = cookie.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }

        if (userId != null)
        {
            session.setAttribute("loggedInUser", userService.findByUserId(userId));
            return "redirect:/";
        }
        else
        {
            model.addAttribute("login", new Login());
            model.addAttribute("register", new Register());
            model.addAttribute("registering", false);
            return "login";
        }
    }
}
```

Is it normal that my request object is null when deleting this cookie?  Am i not correctly replicating the Spring session timing out by deleting it?  This NullPointerException only happens when deleting this cookie and upon first running the web app, the controller does not thrown the exception when the cookie is created by the first run.  Should i somehow be checking for this null value and redirecting the controller back to this method if it is?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried adding a check for null on the HttpServletRequest object and redirecting to / again if it's null but the same thing happened.  I asked another person on my network to browse to my app and he's also getting NullPointerException on the first browse, refreshing the page works correctly since the cookie is created on the first browse.  This means I am indeed correctly replicating the Spring session invalidation by deleting the cookie and that indeed this is an issue.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I also tried using @CookieValue("MDHISStaySignedIn") String cookie as a parameter for my home method but it throws an HTTP Status 400 message complaining it can't find the cookie if said cookie is not there (which it won't be if the user didn't choose to stay signed in).  How can i access cookies using something else than the HttpServletRequest object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the following method parameter :

```
@CookieValue(value = "MDHISStaySignedIn", defaultValue = "notFound") String cookie
```

This will assign the content of the cookie to the value if it's present and assign "notFound" if it is not.  This way one can access cookies when the request object is null!